# Printing specific lines from text file using cmd

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am writing a script that searches a particular account numbers, should flip its sign and print the rest if the lines as it is.
Data in the file:
Org1,Nov,300,771717.684,874790.678,874790.678,874790.678
Org2,Nov,304,-647647.789,-647647.789,-647647.789,-647647.789
Org3,Nov,670,-67890.908,-67890.908,-67890.908,-67890.908
Org4,Nov,671,89765.908,89765.908,89765.908,89765.908
...............
.............
..............
and the rest of the rows
My script is as below:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

SET "source=Test.txt"
SEt "target=test001.txt"
set "search2=670"
set "search1=669"

rem searches for "669" and finds the number of lines till that
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^.*,.*,%search1%" %source%') do set /A lines=%%a-1

rem Reading from the source file
< %source% (


rem Print the number of lines before the search1

rem Copy the lines previous to target one
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do set /P "line=" & echo !line!


  rem Read and process the search1 line
  set /P "line="
  for /F "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%a in ("!line!") do (
  set "data1=-%%d" & set "data2=-%%e" & set "data3=-%%f" & set "data4=-%%g"
  echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!data1:--=!,!data2:--=!,!data3:--=!,!data4:--=!)

Rem here the script finds  670 and prints that line, this works perfect
for /F "tokens=1-7 delims=," %%a in ('findstr /R "^.*,.*,%search2%" 
%source%') do (
set "data1=-%%d" & set "data2=-%%e" & set "data3=-%%f" & set "data4=-%%g"
echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!data1:--=!,!data2:--=!,!data3:--=!,!data4:--=! )>> 
%target%

Rem her the script should pick the lines after the row that has 670 in it, which could be in any lines in the script 

for /F "delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do set /A linea=%%b


for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^.*,.*,%search2%" %source%') do set /A linez=%%a+1

Rem print lines starting after the row that has 670 till the end of file
< %source% (
for /L %%i in (%linez%,1,%linea%) do set /P "line=" & echo !line! )>> 
%target%
```

so the output should be:

```
Org1,Nov,300,771717.684,874790.678,874790.678,874790.678
Org2,Nov,304,-647647.789,-647647.789,-647647.789,-647647.789
Org3,Nov,669,67890.908,67890.908,67890.908,67890.908
Org4,Nov,670,-89765.908,-89765.908,-89765.908,-89765.908  
...............  
.............  
..............
```

Please guide me in this.
Thanks

Comment: There are details missing, please provide a [mcve] in your edited question.

Comment: `more +%linez% %source%>>%target%`

Comment: Hi @LotPings , please see the edited version of question and thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Stephan, could you please tell me where/how I should be using this 
 "more +%linez% %source%>>%target%"  line? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The 1st findstr will number the lines,
- the 2nd filter for search2 in the 3rd col
- The `for /f` will split the line number

---

```
@echo off&setlocal
Set "source=Test.txt"
Set "target=test001.txt"
Set "search2=670"
Set "LineZ="
For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr /n "^" "%source%" ^|findstr "^[0-9]*:.*,.*,%search2%" '
) Do If not defined LineZ Set "LineZ=%%A"&Set "Line=%%B"
(Echo:%Line:-=%
 More +%LineZ% "%source%"
)>"%target%"
```

It's unclear to me what the string substitution with `-` is for.

**Edit** included the removal of the minus.

Comment: the row with 670 will always have data in negative which needs to be positive, so that                                                                                       
     set "data1=-%%d" & set "data2=-%%e" & set "data3=-%%f" & set "data4=-%%g"   converts into positive number

Comment: Hi @LotPings, Will this minus removal edit works if the data is positive and should be in negative?

Comment: No it simply substitutes any possible occurence of a `-` in the line with nothing. How could a batch determine if a sign is wrong? If you mean to exchange a `+` with a `-` simply `Echo:%Line:+=-%`

Comment: I meant that the data could be positive or negative and it should flip signs.for example if data is in negative then it should become positive and if it is negative then the script should add "-"

Comment: This is a totally new question and should be asked as that. Your above sample doesn't even mention signs. Do all the values in a line have the same sign? Is there always a sign or are they absent with positive sign? PU t all this information into a new question.

Comment: sorry for that, the requirement changed again, so had to ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing/extending the question underway is a bad decision because:

- Follow up readers have problems to understand whats going on without reading the edits of the question and all of the comments.
- you limit the audience to your question which is mostly focused on unanswered/unchecked questions.

---

So please when you've got a satisfying answer, **ask a new question**

Your last request of flipping the sign isn't that easy with floating point numbers in batch because the only variable type is string (converted to an integer in `Set /A` and `If` statements if possible).
I guess my following batch is overly complex:

- passing the line to a sub
- storing the fields into an array Arg%%I
- iterating Arg 4..7 spliting at the `.` and multiplying the integer part with `-1`
- storing the result back into the array
- reassembling the line from all array elements.

In analogy to the quote from [Pascal,Goethe,Twain](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal#Quotes) I didn't have the time to write a shorter batch ;-)

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "source=Test.txt"
Set "target=test001.txt"
Set "search2=670"
Set "LineZ="
For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr /n "^" "%source%" ^|findstr "^[0-9]*:.*,.*,%search2%" '
) Do If not defined LineZ Set /A "LineZ=%%A,Cnt=0"&Call :Sub %%B
(Echo:%Line:-=%
More +%LineZ% "%source%"
)>"%target%"
Goto :Eof

:Sub
If "%~1" Neq "" Set /A Cnt+=1&Set "Arg!Cnt!=%1"&Shift&Goto :Sub
For /l %%I in (4,1,7) DO For /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%N in ("!Arg%%I!"
  ) DO Set /A "Arg%%I=-1*%%N"&Set "Arg%%I=!Arg%%I!.%%O"
Set "Line="
For /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%L in ('Set Arg') Do Set "Line=!Line!,%%L"
Set "Line=%Line:~1%"
```